# What is the point of an active shape model in facial recognition?

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision

From what I understood, the Active Shape Model (ASM) is used in facial recognition. I figured out how the ASM works but I don't get why we use it.

How this shape is suppose to be interpreted for facial recognition? Should it be compared directly to the database?

I have read many research papers about ASM and facial recognition but none of them explains the point of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The active shape model algorithm is used to locate precisely the eyes, eyebrows, nose and mouth of a person. It is also used to align faces that are tilted.
It is not used directly for face matching and it has nothing to do with databases. It is a preprocessing step.
You (I) will need another algorithm to match its result with a database. (ICA for example)